# Wait until <script> finishes loading before executing next step

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to get code to execute in the correct order. I first need to add some Google Maps code into the DOM using: 
    `$('body').append('<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Y2E3g8n-jAT0gPXPuHr9mq8zj8uYSbV4&callback=createMap"></script>');`

Then I need to reset the center of the map when a new selection is made from a list:
    `map.setCenter({lat: latitude, lng: longitude});`

Right now setCenter() doesn't work the first time I run it, presumably because the callback function createMap() has added the  to the DOM, but the script itself has not finished. Is there a way I can wait until the script finishes executing before running setCenter()?

Comment: We need to see the code you are trying to use.

Comment: I included the relevant code in the post. `$('body').append('<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Y2E3g8n-jAT0gPXPuHr9mq8zj8uYSbV4&callback=createMap"></script>');` is the code that is taking a long time to finish, and `map.setCenter({lat: latitude, lng: longitude});` needs the first code to finish before executing.

Comment: There is nothing relevant about that code whatsoever. Specifically you're not showing us the "createMap" callback function. which is where the work  is done of creating the map.

Comment: `function createMap() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var mapProp = {center: center, zoom: 14};                 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("geoMap"),mapProp);
    var markers = latLngArray.map(function(location, i) {
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
      });
    });
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}`

Comment: My question has less to do with speeding up the existing execution and has more to do with figuring out how to wait for the execution to finish before proceeding to the next step

Answer (score 0):

The callback `createMap` is where you "wait until the script finishes executing before running setCenter()". That's what the callback is used for. Without showing us the actual code (and not in a comment) of what you are trying to do and how, we can't really help you.

Now I understand if your code is so super secret that you can't show it to us. In that case re-read the part of this that starts with " Without showing us the actual code"